# Using the ProgressBar with the Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, telerik, kendo-grid, breeze

SO...

1. I want to use this:
   http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/progressbar/angular
2. With this:
   http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/the-grid-widget

We already have the Grid implemented and working, but the hurdle is that the basic progress indicator doesn't work for us and I'm tasked with getting the ProgressBar into place because in some cases we have extremely long load times for huge record sets.

Has anybody got this to work, and if so - do you have an example?

I made an attempt to hook into the Grid's data loading process (dataBinding and dataBound), but did not seem to get anywhere.  I have an understanding that another controller may be needed just for the ProgressBar to do its updating, but am hoping I can compartmentalize it to the binding events.

The trickiest part will be making the loading seem as realistic as possible, since the timing on this will vary widely.

We're using Breeze JS and WebAPI service endpoints for loading data.  Breeze is an OData data layer provider for the client-server relationship.

We are using very strict standards around Angular, so using Jquery is not an option to direct hook into the DOM unless I can really justify it cannot be done any other way.

- Here's the Progress Bar API:
  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/progressbar
- Here's the Grid API:
  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid
- And the BreezeJS Api:
  http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/index.html

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance anyone can provide.  Let me know if you need code samples, but the API pretty much provides everything.

Answer (score 1):

I used a **column template** and got the progress bar working in the grid, all angular-zen.

With the grid set up using angular-kendo directives like this:

```
   <div kendo-grid="grid" k-data-source="gridDataSource" k-selectable="multiple" 
                          k-columns="columns"></div>
```

In the controller I put, say:

```
    $scope.columns = [

    { "field": "Name", "title": "File Name", width: 50 }, 

    {"field":"progressBar","title":"progress", width: 70,
      template: "<div style='width: 100%' kendo-Progress-Bar k-value='dataItem.Progress' > </div>"}

    ];
```

and everything worked!

***dataItem.Progress*** is a field  in your datasource, or underlying js array,and the value for your progressbar.

Comment: Hi, I am using this technique however the animation speed does not persist when I am updating the dataItem.Progress value. I need to slow it down. Any Suggestions?